# Reloading Google Map View when adding and removing markers

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

We are coding in Swift to create an application with UI buttons. These UI buttons will add or remove markers depending on its status. Because we want the buttons to be layered on top of google maps we have two view controllers. The top view controller contains a button. When the button is pressed, we want to remove the markers that have a "bad" status.

This is our code to remove the marker:

```
func showOnlyGood(){
   mapView.clear() //this is the google map (GMSMapView.map)
   for x in arrayOfGood { //Array of good markers
      x.map = mapView //Set good markers to show
   }
   for y in arrayOfBad { //Array of bad markers
      y.map = nil //removes markers from map
   }
}
```

The google maps gets updated if the function call is in viewDidLoad(), but when we call the function in the top view controller with the buttons it does not update the map accordingly.

We think this is an issue with refreshing the google map view and have tried many different solutions, but the google map view only shows what is initially in viewDidLoad().

Comment: can you please add values of arrayOfGood and arrayOfBad?

Comment: arrayOfGood and arrayOfBad consist of Google Map's Marker objects

Comment: can you please add those value in your question?I didn't get your point(marker means marker image or location)?

Comment: so google maps has its own API with a marker object. a marker is a pin on the map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you just want the buttons to be layered on top of the map, just add the buttons to the view after you've added the map to the view; do not create a second view controller. Your problem is most likely caused by this awkward setup. You also don't have an `@objc` prefix in your action method, which would definitely prevent the button from executing its action.

```
@objc func updateButtons() {
    mapView.clear() // clear the map
    for i in someArray {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        // configure parameters
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}
```

That method will update your map's markers. There is [probably] never a need to refresh the map, even if you want to change styles.

Comment: Using a container view setup often helps keep code better organized.  It's not more awkward, just more advanced.  As a separate view controller, it can be applied more easily atop other views that are controlled by other view controllers, both in this app and in future apps.  View controllers managing map views are especially prone to getting massive so this is a good way to break things up to discrete (and reusable) units of code.

Comment: I don’t know the setup but OP said he wants buttons on top of a map that toggles between two sets of markers on that map. Introducing a second view controller to hold the buttons is a terrible design approach, if that is the reason which he states it is.

Comment: Yes, I did that because I wanted it to be layered but I will definitely change that aspect. I am relatively new to creating apps, but do have a background in coding.

Comment: @slickdaddy I also have an issue where if I do put it all into one view controller, the buttons appear behind the map. How would I correctly layer these components so that the buttons are on top of the map?

Comment: Simply add the buttons to the view after you’ve added the map to the view.